# Checking if a letter is in a character array python

Tags: python, arrays, character

How would I write a small program that takes an array of characters and a search character and prints true if the search character is in the array, and false if it is not?

Comment: `print (ch in arr)`

Comment: Give it a shot yourself and come back if you have a specific question/problem with your code you can't resolve.

Comment: Perhaps a source of the confusion if you're coming from some other languages is that there's no distinction between `char` and `str` in Python.

Answer (score 2):

In Python this kind of thing is very easy.

`search_character in arr`

Evaluates to False when an item is not in an array and True otherwise.